# On manifolds which do not admit (smooth) actions of finite groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

**Question**: Assume a smooth manifold $M$ does not admit any effective smooth group actions of finite groups $G \neq 1$, does it follow that $M$ also admits no *continuous* effective group actions of finite groups $G \neq 1$?

Manifolds which do not admit actions of finite groups are interesting because if $M$ is compact and we choose a Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$, then $\text{Isom}(M,g)$ is a compact Lie group by Steenrod-Myers and must be trivial, because otherwise it contains a non-trivial finite group acting on $M$.

For this nice property, it is enough to consider only smooth actions.

However, there are some interesting [articles](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606714v1.pdf) which construct manifolds which do not admit any *continuous* actions of finite groups.
And so I'm wondering if its enough to eliminate smooth actions if the manifold is smooth to get a manifold of this type.

Comment: Restatement of the question using group theory language: *If $\mathrm{Diff}^\infty(M)$ is torsion-free, does it follow that $\mathrm{Homeo}(M)$ is torsion-free?*

Comment: The linked article of V. Puppe seems to say "manifold" for "(connected) closed manifold". Is the same implicit assumption made in the question?